# Can a variable be treated as a function?

Tags: c#, function, variables

Say, I have the following program:

```
private int Function()
{
  return 0;
}

public void Function_Deus()
{
  int variable = Function();  

  if (variable(0))  // IS THIS POSSIBLE?
    {
      Console.Writeln("Success");
    }
}
```

My question is, ***what is really happening here***? When `varibale(0)` is called (as a function?), is it checking whether the value of that variable is 0 or something else entirely?

Comment: If you had tested this, you'd know it's a compile-time error.

Comment: "No, you can't" if you know C# syntax.

Comment: It would even be an error, because `Function()` doesn't have an argument.

Comment: This isn't possible, but what you are trying to do might be. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something similar with delegates:

```
private bool IsZero(int value)
{
    return value == 0;
}

public void Function_Deus()
{
    Func<int, bool> variable = IsZero;

    if (variable(0))  // IS THIS POSSIBLE?
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
}
```

Note that your example was wrong in multiple ways, one of which was that `Function()` didn't need any parameter, while you were trying to use it as `variable(0)`

> is it checking whether the value of that variable is 0

This isn't C/C++: `if` works only on `bool` results (or values that have some special `operator` defined, but lets ignore this). Note that my `IsZero` returns a `bool` :-)

Comment: Note that his syntax wouldn't be valid C++ either.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski If *variable* was a function pointer of type `(int)(int)` it would work

Comment: Yes, or a functor with an `operator()`, I meant it wouldn't work with an `int` like in the OP.